# Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Relatively new to PDO (and OOP in general), my **3** named parameters are giving me an error. This is the function I have written to check if a value already exists in the database (so I won't have duplicate entries):

```
function checkTable($table, $column, $value, $con) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM :tbl WHERE :col = :val");
    $stmt->execute(['tbl' => $table, 'col' => $column, 'val' => $value]);

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Of course $con is the PDO connection (yes I have checked, it is connected and I can run normal queries on the database)
I am calling the function with this piece of code:

```
checkTable("posts", "title", "title", $con);
```

I'm expecting to see `true` being returned, as the value I'm putting in **does** exist in the database, but all I'm getting is

```
'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'
```

**EDIT**: I've tested this outside a function, and this worked just as expected:

```
$bind = ['tbl' => "posts", 'col' => "title", 'val' => "title"];
$query = query("SELECT * FROM :tbl WHERE :col = :val", $con, $bind);
var_dump($query);
```

Where the `query()` function looks like this:

```
function query($query, $con, $bind = null) {
    try {
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($bind);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a bound variable where your query requires an identifier. In your case `:tbl` is a table name - you can't bind a variable to it.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM :tbl WHERE :col = :val")` <= Can't do that. `$tbl="tablename"; $col="column_name";` then `"SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE $col = :val")` <= you can do that.

Comment: placeholders can represent **ONLY** values in a query. Never an sql keyword or a field/table name.

Comment: Thanks Fred, Mike & Marc! Rewrote my code to make it work thanks to you guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use table and column names for substitution within prepared statements. `:tbl` - is a table name. So you have only two tokens in your query `:col, :val`.

Also `:col` would be replaced with `'column_name'` (with quotes). Where condition would be looks like `'column_name'='value'`.

Comment: Excellent, just the answer I was looking for! Rewrote the code to make it work without the named parameters and it works like a charm :-) Thanks!